# Getting Facebook user ID from message dialog

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app that would allow users to invite his friends to an event.

What I want to achieve is that when the host is inviting friends, he can invite those that are not on the app through a button. This would send a message to those invited friends that includes a link to install our app. Once they install the app, they can login and will immediately view events he is invited to. Can this be done?

The concern is that when the user who receives the invitation message and installs the app and logs on, how will the app know the person who logged in is the person that is invited in the first place? If the app cannot associate them, how can we provide the relevant events to him once he has logged in? Is what I want to achieve unattainable?

I think it might be done through the old Facebook API, but their new one will only allow an app to access a user's friends who are also on the app and not those that are not on the app. In this case, is there a way for us to pull the UID of those invited through FB's messaging dialog? And will this work with group chat?

I know that another way will be to do it via phone number confirmation and accessing the user's contacts, but I want the invitation process to be through facebook if that is possible.

Thank you all for your help in advance.

Lok

Comment: Make the link you include unique so you know how sent the invite when the person joins

Comment: It may be a dependency you don't want, but check out http://www.yozio.com/. I understand they do a lot of the heavy lifting for "fingerprinting" app installs.